# Setting permission levels in PHP

Tags: php, session

I have a few pages in PHP, basically one is a login which sets sessions (including user permissions)

so in my database i have columns username, password, user, admin, special and it sets them all in sessions

on each page i have the following code:

```
if($_SESSION["special"] != 'yes')
{
echo 'Access Denied!';
exit();
}
```

so it will stop everything from running.

all of my 'Admin' users do not have the 'special' user level as they should just override this and have access to everything but as the admin users do not have the 'special' user permission, the code above runs and stops the user from seeing the page.

how can i make the 'admin' users override this altogether?

Comment: Seems like a simple `||` (or) structure to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have the following situation: Regular users may or may not have `special == yes` and so gain special access. Admins have `special != yes` but still should gain acces?

```
if ($_SESSION['user'] == 'yes' && $_SESSION['special'] != 'yes') {
    echo 'Access Denied!';
    exit;
}
```

This will now only include persons who are users and don't have special access. Admins and users with special can access the site as if no check ever happened.

Alternatively you could write

```
if ($_SESSION['admin'] != 'yes' && $_SESSION['special'] != 'yes') {
    echo 'Access Denied!';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: whats the best way to set these settings in a database? would i need to have each page name (directrory1/test_page.php) and then a column for each different access level?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on what exactly it is you are trying to achieve (in your question) before I can answer that. Also take a look at other user systems, this problem has probably been solved multiple times (even if not for your individual case you might get the inspiration you need)

Answer (score 0):

Your 'Admin' users must have some other parameter defining them as an Admin, so check for that:

```
if(($_SESSION["special"] != 'yes')||(!IS_ADMIN))
{
echo 'Access Denied!';
exit();
}
```